# MYSQL query to divide count(*) of both the tables and join by Months over years

Tags: mysql

I want to write an SQL query to divide the count of both the tables and later join them to display months with respect to Months and Year.

I have written a query that divides the count of both the tables, but I am not sure how to combine the date field of both the tables, such that, Months vs the Divided count appears.

```
 select 
    (a.count_one / b.count_two) as final_count, 
    a.Months, 
    b.Months 
from 
    (
        select count(*) as count_one, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%M %Y") AS `Months` 
        from first_table
        GROUP BY str_to_date(concat(date_format(`first_table `.`date`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    ) a,
    (
        select count(*) as count_two, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%M %Y") AS `Months` 
        from second_table
        GROUP BY str_to_date(concat(date_format(`second_table`.`date`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    ) b
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
**Month and Year**    **Final_Count**
January 2016              126
February 2016             123
March 2016                 45
....                      ....
...                       ....
...                       ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a joining condition:

```
select 
    (a.count_one / b.count_two) as final_count, 
    a.Months
from 
    (
        select count(*) as count_one, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%M %Y") AS `Months` 
        from first_table
        GROUP BY Months)
    ) a,
    (
        select count(*) as count_two, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%M %Y") AS `Months` 
        from second_table
        GROUP BY Montns)
    ) b
WHERE a.Months = b.Months
```

It would be better to learn to write ANSI JOINs:

```
select 
    (a.count_one / b.count_two) as final_count, 
    a.Months
from 
    (
        select count(*) as count_one, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%M %Y") AS `Months` 
        from first_table
        GROUP BY Months)
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    (
        select count(*) as count_two, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%M %Y") AS `Months` 
        from second_table
        GROUP BY Months)
    ) b
ON a.Months = b.Months
```

Comment: Looks like the `GROUP BY` clauses are needlessly complicated, and could be simplified as `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %Y')`

Comment: Right, or just `GROUP BY Months`.